# How to end program if user enters -1 for the number in a Dynamic Array?

Tags: c++

I am new to coding and trying to create a dynamic array that asks the user for the size of it and asks for input. It then should print. The part that I am having trouble with is that these procedures should repeat as needed or until they enter -1 for the number. I am having trouble with ending the program when they enter -1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int count;
cout << "How many values do you want to store in your array?";
cin >> count;
int *DynamicArray;
DynamicArray = new int[count];

for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        cout << "Please input Values: ";
        cin >> DynamicArray[k];
        if (k == '-1') //This is the part i'm having trouble 

        {
            cout << "The program has ended" << endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << DynamicArray[i] << endl;

    }

delete[] DynamicArray;
return 0;
system("pause");
```

}

//When I enter -1 as an input value, it continues to print it in the output. //I need it to end the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int count;
cout << "How many values do you want to store in your array?";
cin >> count;
int *DynamicArray;
DynamicArray = new int[count];

for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        cout << "Please input Values: ";
        cin >> DynamicArray[k];
        if (k == '-1') //This is the part i'm having trouble 

        {
 if(DynamicArray[k]==-1){

     delete[] DynamicArray;
     cout << "The program has ended" << endl;
     exit(0);
           }
        else 
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << DynamicArray[i] << endl;

    }

delete[] DynamicArray;
return 0;
system("pause");}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am having trouble where to implement this in my code.

Comment: Ahh I see now. Thank you!

Comment: you can accept the answer if you find it helpful :)